# Format for Adding an attribute to .vtu file

Tags: mesh, vtk, paraview

I am trying to add an attribute to a vtu file, the attribute being a mesh metric which is a single value for each triangle in my mesh, the vtu file containing mesh information with the following headers:

```
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
    <UnstructuredGrid>
        <Piece NumberOfPoints="468" NumberOfCells="862">
    <Points>
    <DataArray NumberOfComponents="3" type="Float64"  Format="binary">
    *insert nodes coordinates*
    </DataArray>
    </Points>
    <Cells>
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" Format="binary">
    *insert connectivity info*
    </DataArray>
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" Format="binary">
    * insert offset data*
    </DataArray>
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="types" Format="binary">
    </DataArray>
     ****This is where I inserted my array
    <DataArray type="Float64" Name="meshmetric" Format="binary">
    *insert mesh metric values*
    </DataArray>
    </Cells>
        </Piece>
    </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

I added my mesh metric array after  but it doesn't appear when I load the file to paraview, it could be I didn't place the array correctly b) I didn't know how to view it on paraview. c) I need to change/ add an information to the mesh information in the array `<offset>` or `<type>`
**I am not using python**

Comment: Note that `.vtk` file extension refer to a legacy textual format that the file you share is not. Your file is a `.vtu` (xml based unstructured grid). Can you be more precise on what you did and see in ParaView  ? Any message ? Also, how do you write the file ? How do you add the data ? I advise using the writer from VTK

Comment: Thank  you for your time, yes! it's a .vtu file
I added an array of the values of a mesh metric -I am trying to see these values on my mesh-. It's not appearing on paraview. How I wrote the file: I already have a mesh file I just added that array as decribed above. which VTK writer?

Comment: the "vtk writer": an object of the `VTK` library that handles the file writing from a VTK object. So it ensure that the output is well formatted.
By opposite to open a text editor and enter text (or doing it *via* any programatic text writer).

Answer (score 1):

Your `meshmetric` `<DataArray>` tag is not inside the correct tag.

`<Cells>` is here to define the cells themselves. The associated data should be under a `<CellData>` tag, itself being a sibling of `<Cells>`. So

```
<Cells> ... </Cells>
<CellData>
    <DataArray name='meshmetric'>
     ...
    </DataArray>
</CellData>
```

Some doc is [here](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/VTKFileFormats/#unstructuredgrid)